# Automatically clearing the screen on recompile in sbt

Tags: sbt

I am using sbt with the sbt-revolver plugin and I want to clear the terminal screen (^L) when the project is recompiled (~ re-start). How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define new command `clear`, which would use `jline` to clear the screen. Sbt is using `jline` internally so you shouldn't have to include any extra dependency.

#### `build.sbt`

```
def clearConsoleCommand = Command.command("clear") { state =>
  val cr = new jline.console.ConsoleReader()
  cr.clearScreen
  state
}

val root = project.in(file(".")).settings(commands += clearConsoleCommand)
```

Now you could run your compile like this `~;clear;compile`. This will trigger clear the console followed by compile on each file change (assuming this is what you want).

Comment: Great solution but this doesn't seem to work in an Emacs shell.  Maybe jline has no effect there.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, based on @SethTisue answer:

```
alias clearScreen=eval "\u001B[2J\u001B[0\u003B0H"
```

This line should be added to `~/.sbtrc`, so that sbt will have knowledge of a "clearScreen" command. You can either just invoke the command with `~;clearScreen;compile`

Or make an additional alias like `alias cc=~;clearScreen;compile`

Answer (score 2):

On Twitter, Paul Phillips suggested this method:

```
alias cc = ~ ;eval "\u001B[2J\u001B[0\u003B0H" ;compile
```

source: https://twitter.com/extempore2/status/403564233775775744

Answer (score 2):

This specifically helps when you're doing something in continuous mode, ala `compile:

```
maxErrors := 5
triggeredMessage := Watched.clearWhenTriggered
```

This works as of 0.13.7.  The second line clears the screen before each command runs.  The first line limits the number of errors.  With this config, you only ever have one screen full of errors to work through.  Obviously could adjust maxErrors depending on your sbt window.